# android client socket is not receiving data

Tags: android, tcp

I have a tcp server which is not in java also its a hardware device , I need to send and receve the data ,

I am connecting with server and sending some configuration data using following code

```
         this.clientSocket=new Socket("198.168.1.17",9999);
        this.os=new DataOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        this.in=new DataInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Conncted");


          char data[]={0x03,0x03,0x00};
            byte b[]=new byte[data.length];
          for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
              b[i] = (byte) data[i];
             }
            try {
                os.write(b);
```

Device receives data correctly , now in my tcp client i am not able to receive data , though i write following code just after above code

```
            int size =in.available();
                byte data1[]=new byte[size];
              //  in.read(data1);
                String str=new String(data1);
                System.out.println("Reading data:"+str);
```

It only shows reading data , and string has not data
also i tried about code in thread

```
      public void run(){
try{
    while(true){
        int size =in.available();
        byte data[]=new byte[size];
        in.read(data);
        String str=new String(data);
        System.out.println("Reading data:"+str);



    }
```

in thread it only shows reading data , 
Please help how can i get data from the server also please note server is built in i can not change the server code

Comment: What returns `in.available()`? Are you sure server responded to your request anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what available() method do in code "int size =in.available();"????????

**Solution may be:**
available() method return 0 so you are not able to receive data.

Comment: ok , then how can i wait for server to respond , though server is not senfing \n , means i want to send commands one by one ?

Answer (score 0):

use this code for receiving data from socket. write this code before onCreate.

```
private EditText mInputMessageView;
    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    String username;
                    String message;
                    try {
                        username = data.getString("username");
                        message = data.getString("message");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // add the message to view
                    addMessage(username, message);
                }
            });
        }

    };
```